# How to assign access privilege of file(Stored in file table ) to user(Stored in my user table)

Tags: java

I am writing a repository program in java, I have a User table that contains the users of repository and a File Table that contains all the imported files in repository, in MYSQL database.How can I set access privileges of my files to users?In fact how can I determine which user have witch access privilege(read,write,read and write) to which file in repository?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a file repository then file access privileges should be a concept of your mocel. Wouldn't you usually have a dedicated user for running the file repository program and all of the files would have privileges of that user.

Then the program after authorising the user would read from it's database table what kind of privileges do users have to the files they want to fetch.

Since you're storing files physically in the database as BLOB objects then you should create another table that will store user privilages to these files.

```
create table privileges (
    userid bigint,
    fileid bigint,
    read bool,
    write bool,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid,fileid)
)
```

Then whenever you want to check whether a user has read permission to a file you do

```
select userid, fileid from user u join privileges p on u.id=p.userid join files f on f.id=p.fileid and p.read=1
```

Comment: you mean the access privilege should be stored in user table? Until now i just have users and files, so unfortunately every user can access any file he request.

Comment: if you're writing a file repository system then that means that system must provide a ways of granting and revoking permissions for certain users. File system permissions are a feature of the operating system, your application should provide that feature on top of it.
In a normal file repository system the only way of fetching files would be through the application - meaning it has to manage this permissions itself. How the files are stored on the file repository system (which should be a remote machine) is a completely separate issue.

Comment: The content of the files is stored in a column(Blob) of my File table in server side.My clients after login to server can access and import and export the files and fetch them from data base in server.

Comment: what about performance issues?For example if we have 1000 file in repository and 10 user that have read access to all the files then we will have 10,000 record in privilege table!

Comment: this is where you use groups. all of this really depends on your file repository model.
think how it's done in operating systems - usually a file is assigned to a specific group and there's a bunch of users who are in the group. only a selected few files really have specific user privileges set. A file is owned by a specific user, specific group and other than that it has privileges for users and groups. 
Also in a file repository system you should consider "file groups" that contain multiple files under it that all share the file groups permissions.

Comment: In this case in the privilege table we have groupid instead of userid and the records of the privilege table will be reduced,is it not ? and in the user table we determine which user is in which group.that is right?
Is it a prefered way for repository system that each file may have its own privilege?
Thanks

Comment: In this scenario we have both. we still have a table of userid fileid but since specific user privileges aren't obligatory it's not filled up all the time. the users belong to a group or groups and the files belong to a group or groups.z